# Data structure recommendation

Tags: java, data-structures, complexity-theory, bitset

Developing in Java, I need a data structure to select N distinct random numbers between 0 and 999999 ?

I want to be able to quickly allocate  N numbers and make sure they don't repeat themselves.

Main goal is not to use too much memory and still keep performance reasonable.

I am considering using a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) But I am not sure if the memory implications.
Can someone tell me if the memory requirements of this class are related to the number of bits or to the number of set bits? and what is the complexity to setting/testing a bit ?

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the replies so far.

I Think I had this in my initial wording of this Q but removed it when I first saw the BitSet Class.
Anyway I wanted to add the following info:
Currently I am looking at N of a few thousands at most (most likely around 1000-2000) and a number range of 0 to 999999.
But I would like my choice to take into consideration the option of increasing the range to 8 digits (i.e. 0 to 99 999 999) while keeping N at roughly the same ranges (maybe increase it to 5K or 10K). 
So the "used values" are quite sparse.

Comment: Depending on the value of N, using 1 million bits (which is about 100 KiB) is much more space-efficient than maintaining a collection of N numbers.

Comment: Using a BitSet will take ~100K (999999/8 bytes + a bit of overhead).  This is about as cheap as it gets to store up to a million random numbers (which would take (7+mb of ram if using an array).

Comment: I have added an update with number ranges and estimate of N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how large `N` is.

For small values of `N`, you could use a `HashSet<Integer>` to hold the numbers you have already issued.  This gives you `O(1)` lookup and `O(N)` space usage.

A `BitSet` for the range 0-999999 is going to use roughly 125Kb, regardless of the value of `N`.  For large enough values of `N`, this will be more space efficient than a `HashSet`.  I'm not sure exactly what the value of `N` is where a `BitSet` will use less space, but my guestimate would be 10,000 to 20,000.

---

> Can someone tell me if the memory requirements of `BitSet` are related to the number of bits or to the number of set bits?

The size is determined either by the largest bit that has ever been set, or the `nBits` parameter if you use the `BitSet(int nBits)` constructor.

> and what is the complexity to setting/testing a bit ?

Testing bit `B` is `O(1)`.

Setting bit `B` is `O(1)` best case, and `O(B)` if you need to expand the bitset backing array.  However, since the size of the backing array is the next largest power of 2, the cost of expansion can typically be amortized over multiple `BitSet` operations.

Comment: So If I want this to scale to a range of 0-99999999 the BitSet would take around 12.5Mb of memory. While using the HashSet<Integer> would remain O(N) space. I think HashSet would probably be the better solution for my case.

Comment: @epeleg - I think so too.  But you are probably spending too much time worrying about this anyway.  Even 12.5Mb for a data structure is "chicken feed" on a typical 4Gb PC.

Comment: only that it is not running on a 4Gb PC :) and if I can save some (a lot of) memory I would like to do so...
You can also have a look at my Q regarding initialization of the HashSet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308987/initial-capacity-for-a-hashsetinteger

Answer (score 0):

A `BitSet` will take up as much space as 1,000,000 booleans, which is 125,000 bytes or roughly 122kB, plus some minor overhead and space to grow. An array of the actual numbers, i.e. an `int[]` will take N × 4B of space plus some overhead. The break-even point is

```
4 × N = 125,000
N = 31250
```

I'm not intimately familiar with Java internals, but I suspect it won't allocate more than twice the actual space used, so you're using less then 250kB of memory with a bitset. Also, an array makes it harder to find the duplicates when you need unique integers, so I'd use the bitset either way and perhaps convert it to an array at the end, if that's more convenient for further processing.

Setting/getting a bit in a `BitSet` will have constant complexity, although it takes a few more operations than getting one out of a `boolean[]`.

Comment: You got the right answer, but each `boolean` in a Java `boolean[]` actually occupies 8 bits.  What you really mean is "bit" not `boolean`.

Comment: @StephenC: I didn't mean an array of booleans, I meant an array of integers.

Comment: That's not the point.  In Java 1,000,000 `boolean`s will occupy 1,000,000 bytes of memory, not 125,000.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will go with the suggestion to use a HashSet<Integer>.