# Initial capacity for a HashSet<Integer>

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashset

What Initial Capacity should I use for a HashSet into which I know that I am going to insert 1000 integers to prevent the need for any internal rebuilds ?

At first I though that I should use 1000 but reading the description of the constructor that taks the initialCapacity parameter it says `Constructs a new, empty set; the backing HashMap instance has the specified initial capacity and default load factor (0.75).`.

So If I set capacity to 1000 the hashMap will resize when reaching 750 elements?

Also I assume that some "space" is required for the effectiveness of the hashMap so solving IC*0.75=1000 to get something like 1334 might also not be the best solution or is it?

**UPDATE:**
1) I am aware that the implication of internal re-size is not a significant one but still its a chance to learn and better understand the environment which I am using. and the effort should be minimal.

2) Several comments where made regarding the choice of data structure. Please have a look at my previous Q here: [Data structure recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299937/data-structure-recommendation) where more exact information is provided about my scenario.

Comment: Are you going to insert more than 1000 integers?

Comment: So why don't you use this constructor then? `HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) `

Comment: Those nanoseconds must be really important to you.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I am going to insert exactly 1000 integers.

Comment: If you know that you're going to be using 1000 integers and that you're trying really hard to avoid rebuilds, would a more specific data structure be appropriate?

Comment: @Jeroen, Maybe I should. I am trying to understand what parameters to use for it.

Comment: @Brian yes I care for them :) but its also a matter of understanding how things work. otherwise - why provide constructors that allow such control to begin with ?

Comment: @chrylis Maybe so. My Original Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299937/data-structure-recommendation was about the suitable data structure. you can comment on this on that Q or here if you like.

Comment: @epeleg - I guess you meant to comment under my answer. Nevermind. You make a valid point however

Comment: @epeleg You're running into a space/time tradeoff. If 12MB is too much space for you, then you're going to have to use a slower data structure.

Comment: @BrianRoach please see my comment above as it was for you not for Brian Agnew

Comment: @chrylis - yes. I don't see a reason to take 12MB if it can be done with much less. but this is not the point in the Q. I am aware of the fact that there is a trade off and its always hard to choose... but my Q here was about choosing the right initial capacity. I can run my code with the default constructor and it will work. but I have more information (number if Items I will insert) and I want to use it to my advantage and those few nano/pico/whatever second fragments. It feels like there is a number that will save resizes and still not force more memory usage then the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `size/load-factor` to avoid a resize. Note: it will always be the next power of 2 for HashSet & HashMap.

Comment: what will be a power of two? the ratio or the size? (obviouly not the load-factr). also I am guessingone of the HashMap in your answer should be a HashSet ...

Comment: @epeleg The capacity of the number of buckets is always a power of 2.  This is used so a bit mask replaces a modulus in finding the right bucket for a hash.

Answer (score 2):

If it's *really* worth worrying about this (and I suspect it's not - resizing a set of 1000 integers won't take long), then bear in mind that `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap` and the `put` method references [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.addEntry%28int,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,int%29):

```
addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {

   Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];

   table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
   if (size++ >= threshold)
      resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

It's always worth [checking out the source cod](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java)e for such queries, although bear in mind the implementation may always change (even for *minor* JRE releases).

Finally, is a set *appropriate* for this scenario ? If you have a fixed size of integer allocation, perhaps a simple array (using primitives and thus avoiding boxing) would be faster/simpler ?

Comment: It is always interesting to know the reasons to downvote good and correct answer. Downvoters, take a minute to explain your reasons!

Comment: Yes. I would second that!

Comment: Thanks for the reference to grepCode - I did not know it. I also agree about the down votes. But I am missing your point in showing this specific piece of code. As for choice of data structure have a look at my previous Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299937/data-structure-recommendation As it better explains the full scenario.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, it is reasonable to set the initial capacity to 1000 and the load factor to 1 as two **different** `Integer`s will not share the same hash (which is the int itself).

Nevertheless, for general purpose you should not really care about the load factor and leave it as it is as you will probably never notice any improvement setting it yourself. Increasing the load factor may actually lead to dramatic decrease in performance.

Comment: If you must set the `load factor` and `initial capacity` I believe this is the best answer.  Set the capacity to exactly what you need and the load factor to require a full set.  Since your set size is fixed it should never reload.

Comment: how can the integers be the hash key themselves? suppose they come form a range of 0-999999? and the hashMap has only 1000 buckets... Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the ideal initial capacity would be to keep it to the number of integers you want to insert, and the load factor be left to the default.

go for <# of integers>/0.75 load factor.

Comment: does this not promise me with a 100% certainty at least on rebuild ?